# Why isEnable is not called to handler?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have command with button on toolbar.

I have logic for the visibility button.

In some cases the logic is not trigger by eclipse.

It occurred when I move to new Eclipse ( luna )

this is the manifest

```
  <command
        id="RunObjectCommand"
        name="%RUN_XTOL">
  </command>
 <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI= "toolbar:myView">
     <command
           commandId="RunObjectCommand"
           icon="icons/lrun_obj.gif"                              
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
  </extension
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="RunObjectHandler"
        commandId="RunObjectCommand">
  </handler>
  </extension>
```

The Handler that doesn't called all the time

```
  public class RunObjectHandler extends AbstractActionHandler {
  @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
       .............
    }

   @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() { 
    }
}
```

maybe I need to add some logic to the manifest ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse Luna does not update the tool bar as often as before.

You may be able to get your handler updated using:

```
IEventBroker eventBroker = (IEventBroker)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class);

eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID);
```

`IEventBroker` is `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.events.IEventBroker` in the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services` plugin. `UIEvents` is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.UIEvents` in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench` plugin. This code is new to Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Before the isEnable  was called by the eclipsse  . When I need to call to this code?di I need to override any method?

Comment: My Handler is extends from AbstractHandler, do I need to change it ?

Comment: Where I need to add this logic ?

Comment: This code should make Eclipse call your `isEnabled`. You call this in the part of your code where you want the toolbar to be updated.